OAuth 2.0 problem from a 3rd party for Android/iOS
I'll keep the name of the provider under my hat. I think it has an issue with Android/iOS.
They want:
POST /oauth/authorize

with a few parameters (the client key, the redirect url, etc...)  as the first call to start the oauth flow. The response comes back with location header to go a html page for the login.
With that, it looks like they want us to open a browser to send that first POST to /oauth/authorize.   But I don't believe there's any reasonable way to open a browser in either Android or iOS with a POST.
I've tried sending that initial post within the app, and telling the http client to not do the redirect, then trying to open a browser with the url in the location header, and trying to supply the other headers.  They aren't documenting what's in that response (In fact the documentation indicates a JSON object as a response, but that's not happening).  I haven't been able to get that to work either. That does get as far as showing the login page, but after the user logs in, it results in an error (a 404).   I'm guessing that's because I didn't supply whatever was needed for it know who the partner is, and therefore can't find the redirect link that the app catches to grab the token.
I have tested sending the redirect link via adb that the app catches it.  And it does.
I don't want to be too quick to tell them their oauth implementation is broken, but it sure feels like it is.
My understanding is both Android and iOS will need to start the external browser with a simple url.   The browser will almost certainly send it as a GET.
To add insult to injury, they aren't responding to support emails or returning calls.
I'm hoping somebody might be able to give me a way to make this work or confirm that it's broken.

This sounds like a very standard Oauth flow.  How do you want to authenticate your users?  If you use this flow you will redirect to the IDP for the user to enter their credentials and, ultimately, get a JWT back.  You should be able to use a Webview type of interaction for this.

They don't want use to use Webview, they want it completely outside the app.  And we can get the flow going to point where we get the JWT back.  For some other OAuth flows we send a request in the app that returns a code, we plug that code into a url, open the browser with that, and that logs the user in, and redirects to us with the token. I suppose I could give a Webview a whirl as a test balloon.

You may need to host your own web service to support this. Your mobile app would start with a GET to this web service (using ASWebAuthenticationSession on iOS),  your web service will execute the POST and return the response to the mobile client

@Paulw11 I was that kicking around doing that.  I just need to think through it.  But your comment actually helped me think through it.   Thank you.

I implemented a web service as @Paulw11 suggested.  The results are about the same as when I tried to catch the redirect url and its headers and start the browser with them.  Namely it brings up the login page, I log in, and it redirects to a bad page.  I would expect it redirect to my custom redirect url, but it does not.  It's hard to say what it doesn't like, and as I said previously, they haven't responded other then an autoresponder.  It might be that it doesn't like something I'm sending, but I don't think page not found is ever the right response to login.

At this point you either need to provide more information or work with the provider. What page are they redirecting to that gets a 404?  Is it a page in their domain or yours?  Have you tried using a known good oauth client in your server such as something from passport.js ?

The login page redirects an to one of their pages, it looks it redirected to browser to one of the rest apis (which isn't meant for browser).  I suspect this is because the way I got to the login page lost cookies/headers that tied things to my partner account.  So it doesn't my custom redirect url.  I'm about to try having my service return javascript that'll do the initial POST.  So the original POST is done in the browser.

Here's how I got it to work:
I set up my webservice to return an html page with a form that contains the post info, and one line of js to submit it.
I had tried making the post via javascript, but then it's tricky getting the results back to browser.  With putting up the form, the whole flow is being done by the browser (sure the js was running in the browser, I really need that responses to be parsed directly by the browser).
